# Basic Tip Calculator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, innerhtml, getelementbyid

My very basic tip calculator is not working. I feel my logic is right and syntax should be ok, but I am missing something and I already spent too much time on this. Please help. Thank you so much.

```
<body>
<input type='number' placeholder='Total price' id='user-input'/>
<button id="calculator">Calculate the tip</button>
<h3 id='result'></h3>
<script>
  var userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');
  var button = document.getElementById('calculator');
  var h3El = document.getElementById('result');
  button.addEventListener('click', tipCalculator);
  function tipCalculator(){
    var tip = userInput * 0.1;
    h3El.innerHTML = tip;
  }
  tipCalculator();
</script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you told what isn’t working, what errors you are getting and not just nu ”it isn’t working”

Comment: When I input a number and press the button it shows NaN. it doesn`t do the calculation.

Comment: that happens because you are. multiplying a number with HTML element and not a Number

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');
```

to this

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('user-input').value;
```